# In general relativity, assuming a spherical uniform mass distribution, what is the total energy value of the gravitational field inside the sphere?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, potential-energy, mass-energy, binding-energy

In Newtonian mechanics, assuming a spherical uniform mass distribution, the total gravitational potential energy (gravitational self-energy) inside the sphere is

$$U_{gs}=-\frac35\frac{GM^2}R.$$

1. **In general relativity**, assuming a spherical uniform mass distribution, what is the total energy value of the gravitational field inside the sphere?
2. **In general relativity**, assuming a spherical uniform mass distribution, does "total energy value of the gravitational field inside the sphere" equal the "gravitational self-energy"?

*This question was added after 1 answer.
In general relativity, I have seen many articles about the difficulty of defining the energy of the gravitational field.

**The point of my question is,**

3. **In a weak gravitational field or in near-flat spacetime**, can the energy density of the gravitational field be taken from the total gravitational potential energy obtained from Newtonian mechanics, or from the gravitational self-energy, **as a (good?) approximation?**

Comment: This is a matter of much less concern because your question has a "GR" tag and did not include a "cosmology" tag, but, as this site caters to all education levels, "inside the sphere" might be misinterpreted as "within the ball" of which the sphere is a surface: In at least one cosmological model whose Arxiv preprints can be found by their author's name (Nikodem Poplawski), the local universes of an inflationary multiverse are analogized as resembling "the skin of a basketball", which might be as thin as the fermions of the Einstein-Cartan Theory that he uses (which have a spatial extent).

Comment: This question ultimately hinges on exactly what you mean by a good approximation. GR reduces to Newtonian gravity in an appropriate limit, so anything you can do in Newtonian gravity, you can also do in GR, **in that limit**. If that is a good enough approximation for you, then there's your answer. However, things become much more complicated if you want the approximation to be good enough that it includes relativistic corrections to the Newtonian limit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_energy#General_relativity).

Comment: It helped a lot. Since there is no generalized application method, I am going to define and use ρ_gs=U/V. By the way, would this cause serious problems in near-flat spacetime? This is what I'm curious about.

Comment: Uniform wrt. what radial coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

In general relativity, there is no gauge invariant local definition of the energy of a gravitational field. In simpler terms, there is not a well-defined way to define the total energy contained in a finite region of space. So, while you can take a non-relativistic limit and recover Newtonian gravity, it is not possible to unambiguously generalize the idea of the non-relativistic gravitational energy contained in a region, to GR.

For an asymptotically flat spacetime (such as a lump of matter sitting in isolation), you can define a *mass* or *energy* associated with the space. But, you cannot localize this energy to a region.

Comment: Thank you. But~In cosmology, the energy density ρ is used, and the concept of internal energy U/V is also used. So, U_gs=ρ_gsV, ρ_gs=U_gs/V; That is, why not define and use the equivalent energy density corresponding to the gravitational potential energy?

Comment: In an almost flat space-time, why not define and use the energy density for the total gravitational potential energy? Isn't this a good approximation?

Comment: @Dwill $\rho$ refers to the $00$ component of the *stress-energy tensor* $T_{\mu\nu}$, which gives us a way of defining energy density for matter. What I'm saying is that there is not an unambiguous way to define the stress energy tensor for the gravitational field. (There are some cases where it is useful to do so, like in studying weak gravitational waves, but not in general).

Comment: In the weak field limit, you do recover the Newtonian potential, and you can define the energy density of the gravitational field to some approximation as if you were in Newtonian gravity. The problem is that to answer your question, you need to *generalize* the definition so it applies beyond the Newtonian limit. There's no good way to do that. You might be able to make it work in some special cases in an approximate sense, but ultimately the gravitational energy just isn't a very useful concept in GR in most cases (gravitational waves are one exception where it can be useful).

Comment: You can define a gravitational potential for spherically symmetric spacetimes, that includes a correction to the Newtonian potential; that might be interesting, even though it isn't exactly what you're looking for. (It is a way of solving for the radial part of orbits in the spacetime, not a way to define a gravitational energy). See Eq 7.48 here: https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll7.html. The first three terms on the right hand side are present in Newtonian physics, and the last is the correction due to GR.

Comment: @Dwill If you are really using GR, or relativistic corrections to the Newtonian limit, and not just the Newtonian limit, then you are very likely to run into some kind of problem unless you are very careful. Just to illustrate some of the problems that can come up, consider the Newtonian definition of gravitational potential energy as the energy required to bring a collection of objects in from infinity and arrange them in a certain way. In GR, unlike Newtonian gravity, because gravitational waves are emitted, the energy required will depend on exactly how you bring the masses together.

Comment: As another extreme example, if in the process of bringing the masses together you have a lot of energy in a small volume, you can form a black hole. The point isn't necessarily that you would emit a lot of gravitational waves or create a black hole, but it shows that the Newtonian idea of the gravitational binding energy doesn't work in GR, because the energy needed to assemble a system is path dependent (due to gravitational waves), and the way you bring the objects together can lead to a different final state (black hole). This is just to illustrate some difficulties in generalizing to GR.

Comment: Thank you very much. Andrew! While I was thinking about dark energy, I discovered the possibility that the source of dark energy is the gravitational action of the gravitational field. However, since it is difficult to define the energy of a gravitational field in general relativity, I assumed and calculated the source of dark energy as gravitational self-energy. Then, the decelerated expansion, the inflection point (which changes from the decelerated expansion to the accelerated expansion), and the accelerated expansion are explained.

Comment: And, calculating the current dark energy value and inflection point, it is similar to the standard cosmology. And, I made a function of time for dark energy. Thank you for reading.  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/360096238

Comment: The source of dark energy is presumed to be gravitational self-energy and the expansion of the particle horizon.

Comment: The reason the question was written is because others keep saying, "Your method doesn't work because the energy of the gravitational field is undefined in general relativity." On the other hand, there is no consensus method in general relativity, so I used this method. And, isn't it possible to use it as an approximate method? So I was curious. Can this be used as an approximation?

Comment: @Dwill I haven't thought about your definition very hard, so I can't give you an argument whether it works or not. But, since you are introducing this definition, and especially since the gravitational energy is known to be difficult to define in GR, I think the burden of proof is on you to demonstrate that your definition makes sense. I would guess that it does not and I don't see any reason to think it is meaningful, but I could be convinced with a strong argument (i.e., one with equations demonstrating that your definition has useful properties you would want energy density to have).

Comment: To be clear, it's known that you can't define a stress-energy tensor for gravity, so the best case is that your definition provides an approximate notion of the gravitational energy density that is good enough for you application. It's very possible that your definition matches this set of criteria -- I can't say without looking in more detail, which realistically I am not going to do. The burden is on you to supply a convincing argument that your definition of gravitational energy density has useful properties when applied to your problem. Since you wrote a paper, we should be asking you.